# How do I calculate the sum of numbers stored in LocalStorage?

Tags: javascript, json, local-storage

I am new to JSON, so bear with me!

I am working on a website that stores values to LocalStorage via inputs.  Each form input has the following function (only difference is formInput2, formInput3)

```
function formInput(e) {
  // Save userInput from input
  // Get form values 
  var input = document.querySelector('.input').value;
  this.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  smtBtn.style.display = 'inline-block'
  var userInput = {
    answer: input
  }

  // Test if bookmark is null
  if (localStorage.getItem('bookmarks') === null) {
    // Init Array
    var bookmarks = [];
    // Add to array
    bookmarks.push(userInput);
    // Set to LocalStorage
    localStorage.setItem('bookmarks', JSON.stringify(bookmarks));
  } else {
    // Get Bookmarks from LocalStorage 
    var bookmarks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('bookmarks'));
    // Add bookmark to array 
    bookmarks.push(userInput);
    // Reset back to LocalStorage
    localStorage.setItem('bookmarks', JSON.stringify(bookmarks));
  }

  // Refetch bookmarks
  fetchBookmarks();

  // Prevent form from submitting
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

I need to add the three numbers that are in local storage, and I am using this function:

```
function bookmarkMath() {
   var bm1 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('bookmarks')),
    total = 0,
    i;
  for (i = 0; i < bm1.length; i++) {
    total += bm1[i].answers;
  }
  console.log(total);
}
}
```

But alas, my output is NaN.  :(

Any help would be very appreciated!!!!!!!

edit:  In dev tools, this is what I get back with console.log(LocalStorage) - the numbers I have entered in the form on the site.

```
    Storage {bookmarks: "[{"answer":"2"},{"answer":"4"},{"answer":"5"}]", length: 1}
    bookmarks: "[{"answer":"2"},{"answer":"4"},{"answer":"5"}]"
    length: 1
    __proto__: Storage
```

Edit 2:  I have updated the second ]function to include the JSON.parse.  But now I am getting just the numbers 0245 as my result, NOT the sum of 0+2+4+5.  Any help?? :p

Comment: You only store *strings*, not objects, you need to transform the string back into an array first...

Comment: You have to use `JSON.parse()`, just like you did in `formInput()`.

Comment: You're missing a `JSON.parse()` call on the string you get back from localStorage

Comment: AHHH!  Yes, thank you!  Okay, now it works, but it is not calculating the sum of the numbers,  my output is "0245" -- any ideas?  thank you guys again so much!!!!

Comment: HTMLInput.value is always a string, you need to coerce it to a number.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track by doing `JSON.parse()`. However, the value is in a string. You can see quote at the value it is mean will be threated as a string. You should convert it to number format like following:

`total += parseInt(bm1[i].answers);`

If you don't want to do `parseInt()` then your output should be :

```
{"answer": 2} //this one mean your value is Number
```

Instead:

```
{"answer":"2"} //this one mean your value is in String
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I see it ... this statement looks "wrong, yet something that JavaScript would accept!"

```
  var bm1 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('bookmarks')),
    total = 0,
    i;
```

*Notice the **commas.***

Instead, write this as three separate lines:

```
var var bm1 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('bookmarks'));
var total = 0;
var i;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const bookmarks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('bookmarks')) || []
const totalAnswers = bookmarks.map(o => +o.answer).reduce((a, b) => a + b)
```